# Visual Studio 2013 C++ IntelliSense shows suggestion but does not commit them by pressing any of the member list commit characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

When I type in a C++ project , I get suggestion. I can commit the selected suggestion by hitting Tab key; But if I press enter or space or any of the member list commit characters :

```
{}[]().,:;+-*/%&|^!=<>?@#\
```

, Intellisense doesn't commit the selected option. I want this suggestion to be committed with any of these characters, exactly as the default settings in C#.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

- Open Options from menus: Tools -> Options
- Navigate to page: Text Editor -> C++ -> Advanced
- Scroll down to Intellisense section
- Change the option: Member List Commit Aggressive from False to True

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi You're welcome. Glad to hear that it worked for you.

Comment: This solution din't work for me. I don't see any option "Member List Commit Aggressive". I see an option "Disable Aggressive Member List" which is by default set to false and I believe this should remain false.

Comment: @Nipun Did you try scrolling down ? the options aren't sorted by name, so you have to read each one of them. What is the version number of the visual studio you use?

Comment: @MuhammadAnnaqeeb, I am using VS2013 and yes I have checked all options but 'Member List Commit Aggressive' not available.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I am using C++ together with Boost. There is a famous linker problem with Boost in debug mode.

I fixed this problem by the preprocessor macro
_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0

But intellisense stopped working. I looked in the Error List tab of Visual Studio and found an entry which says intellisense has a problem wwith this macro.

After I changed this macro to 
_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0

intellisense works perfectly.

Hopefully this will help you
Walter