# How to stop auto complete in Visual Studio 2013 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, autocomplete

I'm having trouble with the auto completion in Visual Studio (C#), because it keeps completing stuff I dont want it to.
For example if I do int x = z; Then when I press z it suggests "DivideByZeroException", and if i press ; then it chooses this completion. I only want to accept the marked auto completion with enter. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in C#. You can do it in C++ [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20342224/61697).

You'll have to press Esc to close the AutoComplete box before pressing `;`.

BTW I think if you had Resharper you could do it.

---

As you mentioned you do have Resharper, you can configure your completion characters from
`ReSharper | Options | Environment | IntelliSense | Completion Characters`
as [documented here](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Reference__Options__Environment__Completing_Characters.html).

Comment: I have respharper actually.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Tools>Options>TextEditor>General UnCheck That you don't want. You can also check All Languages section

Comment: I've looked there, but I can't find any settings that turns it off.

Comment: In SharpDevelop its in Tools>Options>Text Editor>Code Completion