# Visual Studio 2015: C++ IntelliSense suggestion not committed when pressing space

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

What I want from VS2015's autocomplete when coding C++ is that when I start typing the name of a variable, it automatically suggests that variable and when I press space, it commits it (which is the default behavior for C#).

I first had to find out how to make sure the suggestion was actually selected, which I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20342224/2471262.

Sadly, this doesn't fully do what I want it to. When pressing enter, it now automatically commits the variable name. However, this doesn't work for space. When first pressing ctrl+space and then typing part of the variable name, space bar actually works to commit the variable name. So basically this is the result:

Suppose we have a var named abcd.

```
<ctrl+space>ab<enter> => abcd // First two works without changing Member
<ctrl+space>ab<space> => abcd // List Commit Aggressive from False to True

ab<enter> => abcd // Works with Member List Commit Aggressive set to True
ab<space> => ab   // This somehow does not work :(
```

Does anyone know a solution to get the final option to work? Or is this just a bug in VS? It's really annoying not to have it working, since I'm used to it from C#.

Comment: Seems like it might be a bug in the C# Intellisense, that it does not respect the "Commit Aggressive" option.  Please remember that although you may personally have used Intellisense in C# first, the C# Intellisense is actually a clone of the original, C++ one.

Comment: The commit aggressive option is for C++ only, I don't believe C# has such an option, or at least it's not called similarly, nor does it show up under the advanced settings (because there are no advanced settings :P).

However, for the enter key, setting the option to true has the desired effect, but for the space key, it doesn't, even though the suggestion is selected in the suggestion box and that should normally (when using ctrl+space) result in the suggestion being committed when space is pressed. So I think it's actually a bug in C++'s IntelliSense, or I'm missing some option.